# remove alternate rows from sql query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I remove from sql query alternate rows?

for example query returns something like this:

```
1 : 2
2 : 1
```

how can I remove second row?

Comment: Do you want to filter the 2nd, 4th, 6th, ... row? Or do you want to filter out rows where (a,b) = (b,a)? And with "filter" do you mean you want to remove them from a query result, or do you want to delete them from the table all together?

Comment: that's a nice question to be asked!! leads to many assumptions..

Comment: i want filter out rows where (a,b) = (b,a)

Comment: and I want remove them from query result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy to do with one statement:

```
create table myTable as
select 1 col1, 2 col2 from dual
union all
select 2 col1, 1 col2 from dual;

select * from myTable;

delete from myTable outtab
where exists (select null
              from myTable
              where col1 = outtab.col2
                and col2 = outtab.col1
                and col2 > col1);

select * from myTable;

drop table myTable;
```

The key point here is:

```
col2 > col1
```

which does not allow to remove both of the rows but only one.

To remove it from your dataset it is totally the same:

```
select *
from myTable outtab
where exists (select null
              from myTable
              where col1 = outtab.col2
                and col2 = outtab.col1
                and col2 > col1);
```

or `not exists`, as you wish.